# HMAC hashing vs JWTs for stateless authentication

Tags: jwt, hmac

For simple authentication with backend services, without more sophisticated needs (e.g. roles and scopes), is there any security benefit in using JWTs instead of sending HMAC hashes to verify a payload?

HMAC:

1. Client generates a timestamp & payload
2. Client has the secret key already as part of code base
3. Client uses key to generate HMAC hash to validate the payload & prove identity to server since both the client and the server has the shared secret key

JWT:

1. Client sends credentials to authentication server (e.g. ID & Pass)
2. Server checks the credentials against some database and using a secret key, signs a JWT
3. Client receives the JWT, sends it to another backend service to prove identity
4. Backend service checks the signature with the secret key

Comment: That's not really about HMAC vs JWT but about authenticating *a message* using a shared secret between client and server vs. authenticating *an endpoint* using dedicated and maybe third party identity provider. Apart from being different things (authenticating message vs. authenticating endpoint) they come with different complexity and flexibility - and more of this is usually bad for security unless actually needed. So if HMAC provides sufficient flexibility for your use case and if you manage to distribute and update the shared secret securely, then it might be the better option.

Comment: Agreed, hashing signature vs JWT to me are two presentation outcomes depending on where you keep a secret key (client server vs server only). My intuition was that authenticating a message with hashing was less secure because it involves transmitting secrets to client side, but you think it's more secure than JWT way?

Comment: Why does your question cover the actual authentication process in one case ("Client sends credentials... Server checks the credentials against some database") and hand-wave it in the other ("Client gets a shared secret key / has the secret key already")? The latter case says nothing about the process of getting the key (presumably there's some authentication involved at some point?) or the properties of the key (does it expire? Is it unique? Is it random? Where is the server's knowledge of the key stored?). The question is underspecified.

Comment: @CBHacking You are right - those two scenarios can give different security concerns. I've changed the question to client has secret key, which is what I was thinking originally. The key does not have an expiry. The client is likely another backend microservice.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have a doubt when you talk about distributing the shared secret. I have a gRPC service / client application and I use HMAC to signing the JWT token. I only have the password in the server, I don't have it in the client and I don't distribute the password in any place, only is in the server as configuration of the ASP application. When it is needed to distribute the secret outside the server? Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: The case described in the question is about checking the integrity of a message send by some peer, i.e. client checking message from server etc. The case you describe is about checking the integrity of a token issued by oneself, i.e. checking in the server that the server issued JWT token was not modified. In the latter case there is no distribution of a secret needed since using the secret for generating and for checking the HMAC is done by the same party.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the reply. It was what I am thinking. So I guess that in this case, an HMAC it is enough and for performance it is a better option that RSA.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: yes, I think so